# How to find indexof token in a string expression?

Tags: java, regex

How to find indexof "rent" token in a expression. token contains any alphabet number and underscore. token separated by any symbol.

```
String expr = "rent_office+eb+water+rent+eb_office";
```

rent token should return 21 index. any knows how to write regular expression for this to get index of.

Comment: Why 22? Why not 0? Do you want the index of the last occurrence?

Comment: It's probably 22, because some tokenization is involved and "rent_office" should not be considered. @Ingreatway, please clarify.

Comment: I'd make a paper aeroplane out of this spec and send it back to the relevant department.

Comment: Spec is still ambiguous. Why would it not return 0?

Comment: should return 21 because compare absolute token. not part of token.

Comment: In which case "rent" is not a token yet you imply it is in your question.

Comment: @Ingreatway - In that case you want the *complete* word (*rent*) and not the word as part of another word (*rent_office*). right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word boundry like this : `\\brent\\b`

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/tA1vP2/1)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your problem, the token consists letters, numbers and underscores. To break your given string in the token,  you can use `^[\w\d_]+`  regular expression. Using java code below, you can match your token and find the index of your token which will be 21 as you have expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String expr = "rent_office+eb+water+rent+eb_office";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d_]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expr);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group().equals("rent")) {
            System.out.println("start index : " + matcher.start());
            System.out.println("end index : " + matcher.end());
            System.out.println("string : " + matcher.group());
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
start index : 21
end index : 25
string : rent
------------------------------
```